# Two queries side by side - month/year in common (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, left-join

I'm trying to put two queries side by side having month and year in common between them.
They work perfectly individually.

Table Boxes - Looking for boxes per month

```
SELECT count(*) AS Count_Boxes,
DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%b') AS 'Month',
DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%Y') AS 'Year'
FROM boxes
GROUP BY YEAR(create_date), MONTH(create_date);
```

Table Orders - Looking for orders per month

```
SELECT count(*) as Count_Orders,
DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%b') AS 'Month',
DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%Y') AS 'Year'
FROM orders
GROUP BY YEAR(create_date), MONTH(create_date);
```

I have tried so many ways using LEFT JOIN but nothing worked.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join:

```
SELECT o.count_orders, b.*
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) AS Count_Boxes,
    DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%b') AS mn,
    DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%Y') AS yr
    FROM boxes
    GROUP BY YEAR(create_date), MONTH(create_date)
) b
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT count(*) as Count_Orders,
    DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%b') AS mn,
    DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%Y') AS yr
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY YEAR(create_date), MONTH(create_date)
) o ON o.mn = b.mn and o.yr = o.yr
```

However if there is a possibility of missing period on either of the datasets, then another approach uses `union all`:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(no_orders) count_orders,
    SUM(no_boxes) count_boxes,
    DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%b') mn,
    DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%Y') yr
FROM (
    SELECT create_date, 0 no_orders, 1 no_boxes FROM boxes
    UNION ALL       
    SELECT create_date, 1, 0 FROM orders
)
GROUP BY YEAR(create_date), MONTH(create_date)
```